# Is it possible to send data from awk to python without writing files to disk?

Tags: python, awk, text-processing

I have a bunch of output files in a directory, and I am using awk to extract information from them. Once awk has run its course, and I have written my information neatly in a `data.txt` file, I call pandas and create dataframe of my data.

My question is, when I obtain my information from awk, can I instantly throw it in a numpy array/list, using the subprocess module or something?

Comment: Yes, you can use e. g. `subprocess.check_output()` to run awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might pipe (`|`) output of your `awk` into `python` using `sys.stdin.read` from [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) in last. Consider following simple example `countdigits.py` which print number of digits in whole output

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
digits = [i for i in data if i.isdigit()]
print(len(digits))
```

and `file.txt` which content is:

```
1
2
3
```

then

```
awk '//' file.txt | python countdigits.py
```

will output

```
3
```

and

```
awk '{print $0*100}' file.txt | python countdigits.py
```

will output

```
9
```

You might use `|` to transmit any text from `awk` to `python`, without creating textfile.